# Angular2 - Jquery not working

Tags: angular

So I have been having problems getting my [angular app to build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509319/angular2-struggling-to-build-project). In a previous question, someone suggested starting with a fresh install... so out of desperation, this is what I have done.

The following are the new set of problems...

Here it seems that JQuery is not recognised:

```
> ng serve

** NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:4200 **
Hash: d1f891d598c9af6a8b6f                                                               
Time: 5768ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 153 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 119 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 9.77 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 2.99 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]

WARNING in ./src/app/app.component.ts
138:336-345 "export 'AppConfig' was not found in './app-config'

WARNING in ./src/app/app.component.ts
138:365-374 "export 'AppConfig' was not found in './app-config'

    ERROR in ..src/app/app.component.ts (89,5): Cannot find name '$'.)
    ../src/app/app.component.ts (89,18): Cannot find name '$'.)
    ../src/app/app.component.ts (107,9): Cannot find name '$'.)
    ../src/app/app.component.ts (110,11): Cannot find name '$'.)
    ../src/app/app.component.ts (117,9): Cannot find name '$'.)
    ../src/app/app.component.ts (128,9): Cannot find name '$'.)
    ../src/app/app.component.ts (131,9): Cannot find name '$'.)
    ../src/app/app.component.ts (133,11): Cannot find name '$'.)
   ../src/app/app.component.ts (146,9): Cannot find name '$'.)
    ../src/app/app.component.ts (157,42): Cannot find name '$'.)
    ../src/app/app.component.ts (160,9): Cannot find name '$'.)
    ../src/app/app.component.ts (165,11): Cannot find name '$'.)
   ../src/app/app.component.ts (174,5): Cannot find name '$'.)
   ../src/app/app.component.ts (178,9): Cannot find name '$'.)
    ../src/app/app.component.ts (185,5): Cannot find name '$'.)
    ../src/app/app.component.ts (186,7): Cannot find name '$'.)
    ERROR in ../src/app/service/login.service.ts (9,12): Cannot find name '$'.)
    ../src/app/service/login.service.ts (16,17): Cannot find name '$'.)
    ../src/app/service/login.service.ts (17,17): Cannot find name '$'.)
```

Any suggestions as to how to resolve this?

Comment: What are you using jQuery for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are using angular CLI, Did you include in your angular-cli.json file?

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
]
```

Read more about [Global Library Installation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-lib)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these simple steps. It worked for me if you are using angular cli:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42295505/7532440